# Visual studio code comment in HTML files

Tags: html, comments, visual-studio-code, key-bindings, code-editor

I am trying Visual Studio Code lately and i've noticed that when i try to add a line comment in an HTML file (using  Ctrl+/ or Ctrl+K Ctrl+C) instead of this: `<!-- -->`, i get this `{# #}`.

In JS or CSS files the key bindings work just fine and produce the expected result.

So how can i get the proper type of comments in HTML files?

Comment: for me, the offender is Jinja syntax support
took me a while to do the trial-err

Comment: For me the offender was Hugo Language and Syntax Support

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Finally i found what the problem was. I had installed the twig plugin (for the Twig php template engine) and that was causing the comments issue.

Comment: I was getting crazy about this! Thanks!

Comment: Thanks :) If you need Twig support, install this extension instead: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=whatwedo.twig#overview

Comment: Or maybe this one, it looks like it has more features: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mblode.twig-language-2

Comment: I confirm. The problem is with the Twig Language 0.9.0 extension. Use https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=whatwedo.twig#overview and/or https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mblode.twig-language-2 instead.

Comment: This was the issue for me i disabled it , Thanks @tonix

Comment: It was the same for me. Just remove any Twig extrension and you're done! Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was going crazy since last 72 hours.

Answer (score 15):

List of extensions known to cause this unwanted behavior (Based on my own experience and other answers):

- Hugo Language and Syntax Support
- Djaneiro
- Nunjucks
- Tornado
- Sublime Babel
- Babel
- Twig
- Django by Baptiste Darthenay (v1.0.0)
- Tera template formatter
- Livewire Language Support by cierra
- (Feel free to edit this answer and add yours)

You may need to restart code after disabling your extension (I did).

Comment: Jinja (by wholroyd) breaks the commenting ability with ctrl + / when inside embedded css.

Comment: Thank you! I uninstalled Django extensions but didn't realise I had Hugo installed!

Comment: Any workarounds for the jinja one?

Answer (score 6):

If you don't want to disable/uninstall any plugin, you can create a snippet to put a comment. For example, I create a snippet that add HTML comments in a PHP file:

```
    "comment HTML": {
      "prefix": "chtml",
      "body": ["<!-- $1 -->"],
      "description": "Comment HTML line"
    }
```

You can insert that right after the comment in File > Preferences > User Snippets > {YourExtension}

Then, when you start typing 'chtml' in that kind of files, IntelliSense will prompt that snippet.

Maybe this is a workarround, but it works excellent for me. Hope it helps!

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/customization/userdefinedsnippets

Answer (score 6):

For me, it was the (Djaneiro) extension, it made the html files default to django template, so it caused the comments to be wrong in HTML (when pressing ctrl + / )
(commenting them with {% comment %})

Answer (score 5):

I've just installing VSCode 1.1.1 and try to put a comment in an new html file
To do so, your new file must be,first, save in .html format and after that, you can use CTRL-K CTRL-C to put a comment and it works.

Hope that help you

Comment: Well i installed the latest version of VSCode 1.1.1 on a new machine and the comments work as expected. But i still have the issue on my other pc (same version 1.1.1 but got it from updates). 

I think that's maybe a configuration that instead of <!-- --> returns {# #} for HTML files and i want to find that and change it. Or else i 'll try to uninstall and reinstall.

Answer (score 3):

In your Visual Studio Code windows, go to **File->Preferences->Keyboard Shortcut**

This will open two files beside each other like in the screenshot below:

[image]

here you can change or create your own shortcuts.
Like I just replaced **Ctrl+KU** to **Ctrl+/**

Hope this will work for you !!

Answer (score 1):

For me, the offending extension was Nunjucks (the templating language plugin assumes every .html file is a nunjucks html template)

Answer (score 1):

For others having the problem, the Tornado extension is also a culprit.  I had to "disable (workspace)" one by one to find it.

Answer (score 0):

Try uninstalling any python extension packs you may have installed! You can then reinstall the python extension you need individually.

Chances are one of the extensions in the bundle of that extension pack is causing the issue

Answer (score 0):

Click (Ctrl + K C) to comment the html.
Click (Ctrl + K U) to uncomment html.

Comment: that was not the question dude

Answer (score 0):

For me, this was caused by the Sublime Babel extension. Disabling it and restarting VS Code fixed the issue: `Cmd+K, Cmd+C` works again, as does `Cmd+/` for toggling. Also, HTML comment blocks are now correctly styled again.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the file type at the bottom right corner. you probably are on Django HTML. you can set it to HTML.