# Visual Studio Code HTML wrong comment type

Tags: visual-studio-code

I recently used VS code for Wordpress development but I encountered a weird bug when I comment with (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>) to an html element. Instead of commenting (`<!-- -->`) it uses (`//`) for my html code? Has anybody experience this? Do you know of any solutions to change the comment to the correct html comment?

[image: Animated GIF]

Comment: See gif attachment for clarification.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual studio code comment in HTML files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37312056/11683)

Answer (score 16):

This is caused by VS Code improperly auto-detected programming language - in the lower right corner of your GIF you can clearly see, that VS Code is set to HTML. Click on that button, and switch over to **JavaScript (React)** and problem should be solved.

Comment: this is the answer. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 12):

I had the same exact problem. But in the end, I discovered I had an extension which was interfering with the HTML commenting. So I had to disable all extensions and restart VS Code to get back to my usual commenting back again.

Then I did a trial-and-error check (enabling one extension at a time and then reload) to find out the *faulty extension* which I later uninstalled. Try disabling all your extensions to see if it helps you.

[image: Disable all extensions]

Comment: This was the case for me. I had these comment because of the "Hugo Language and Syntax Support" Extension in regular .html files

Comment: Same here thanks for commenting this saved me some time.

Comment: So, this issue is known since pretty much exactly two years & the extension still was not fixed? Wow. Just wow. Had to disable the Hugo extension & now it works!

Comment: @JiiB I love you, you're great, saved me so much time. Wow I was just coding without the comment shortcut and considered reinstalling vscode lol. Thank you <3

Comment: For me it was twig extension

Answer (score 8):

In case it helps anyone else, it was the Go extension that changed all my comment characters to {#.

Comment: My HTML also got `{# ` and `#}` for comment, and it's **Better Nunjucks** in my case, just disabled it in the current workspace.

Comment: **Better Nujucks** just got me too.

Answer (score 7):

For future searchers, this happened to me in a different way: I was getting HTML comments inside a script tag, instead of JavaScript comments.

I disabled the TWIG pack extension and it went back to the expected behavior!

Comment: TWIG was the culprit for me too. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was the Sublime Babel extension that changed the comment code to `//` in HTML mode. Downgrading Sublime Babel from 0.2.10 to 0.2.9 solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

In my case it is the "Hugo Language and Syntax Support" plugin that breaks my HTML commenting: https://github.com/theNewDynamic/language-hugo-vscode/issues/26.

Comment: Disabling the extension for the current workspace worked

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was getting HTML comments inside script tag, instead of JavaScript tag.

I uninstalled Jinja extension and everything went back to normal.