# Comment html code using Visual Studio Code

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, comments

VS Code uses /* */ as comment marks for html.

When I use /* */  for commenting in HTML (either through a shortcut or plain typing) in a block of text I get in edges and green color on the text and the text is commented out.

When i type ">!--  --<" (< and > on opposite direction) the text does not get green.

Language mode is HTML and there are no extensions at all installed!

Comment: VS Code uses /* */ as comment marks for HTML is not true

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Visual studio code comment in HTML files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37312056/visual-studio-code-comment-in-html-files)

Answer (score 0):

"" is used for strings in HTML. Strings are different from comments, as they will be actually read by the interpreter.

Comment: Sorry, I use ">!-- --<" (< and > on opposite direction), not just "". But the page renders comment marks also in the post :)

Answer (score 0):

Comments in HTML follow this format

```html
<!-- comment text -->
```

I don't think comments work with `/* comment */` in HTML.

I'm not sure why VScode seems to be suggesting that. It'd be clearer if you gave some more information, such as code snippets and what you're expecting to see.

Comment: I expect when editing html to comment out using  ">!-- --<" instead of /* */ VSCode use now.

I use the default snippets