# how do I add a comment tag in VSCode for HTML using Emmet?

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts, emmet

How to add a comment tag in HTML using Emmet in VSCode?

What I want:
Before:

```
<div class='abc'>
```

After using Emmet keyboard shortcut:

```
<div class='abc'> <!-- -->
```

Comment: Click (Ctrl + K C) to comment the html.

Comment: Do you see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37312056/visual-studio-code-comment-in-html-files)?

Comment: The problem is that when I click after the closing tag and press Ctrl + K C, it comments out the whole line including the div, like this: <!-- <div class='abc'>-->   The Ctrl KC only works for empty lines. Anyways I found a solution that works. I'll add it as an answer then for future seekers. The shortcut is shift+option+a but I dont know if its emmet or vscode inbuilt.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Emmet has built-in `c` abbreviation which outputs comment

Answer (score 0):

On a mac - it is command+option+"right arrow" - allows you to place a comment on a line that already has content.

Answer (score 0):

There is a command called `Emmet: Toggle Comment` which comments the current line. If you use the keybinding extenstion, it is configured as `Cmd M + Cmd /` .

```
<title>Document</title>
-> 
<!-- <title>Document</title> -->
```