# Visual Studio issue with commenting only in html code

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

I'm recognizing some issues in visual studio code when i want to comment some html code lines. When i press the shortcut `ctrl+k ctrl+c`, it creates the tags `<!--` and `-->` before what i want, but the colors of the font don't become as they should be. The code lines after the comment, become in a wrong color like my comment isn't comment while all the remaining code is. The tags `<!--` and `-->` take a red colour like they are written wrong.

Comment: I using "ctrl + /" shortcut. May be you can find solutions here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37312056/visual-studio-code-comment-in-html-files

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio Code or Visual Studio? You mention both, but these are two completely different products.

Comment: `ctrl+k ctrl+c` put what is selected in HTML comment delimiters

Comment: Add a screenshot of the before and after, and a code block to help people copy-paste to try to reproduce the issue.

Comment: I have VISUAL STUDIO CODE. These are the shortcuts i've put: [shortcuts][1]. Now I show you the code before and after pressing ctrl + E: [before][2] [ctrl+E][3][ctrl+7][4]This is the code: <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous" /> [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ChmKP.png [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wfi7U.png [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PElyv.png [4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RLbLp.png

Answer (score -1):

I have VISUAL STUDIO CODE. These are the shortcuts i've put: [shortcuts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ChmKP.png). Now I show you the code before and after pressing ctrl + E: [before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wfi7U.png)
[ctrl+E](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PElyv.png)[ctrl+7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RLbLp.png)This is the code:

```
    <link
                href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
                <!-- rel="stylesheet" -->
                integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD"
                crossorigin="anonymous"
            />
```