# Change tags for 'Toggle Block Comment'

Tags: visual-studio-code, comments

Until now, when I used the keybind for `Toggle Block Comment` inside a .ejs file, it toggled the HTML parts with `<!-- ... -->` and in script tags with the JS multiline comment `/* ... */`. But since today it just uses `{# ... #}` for the whole file, which obviously doesn't work for the JS inside the script tags. Is there some way to change what commenting tags are being used? Why did this change and was there some change to vscode that changed it?

Answer (score 0):

After searching for solutions online, I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37312056/visual-studio-code-comment-in-html-files) question, which basically states that the Twig Language extension caused this problem.